# How to inject services for classes which inherit from AutoMapper.Profile?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to use the cache service in the `Profile` class. I using `IocManager.Instance` resolve service, but can't unit test.

Answer (score 0):

Create this in your test project.

```
public abstract class TestBaseWithLocalIocManager : IDisposable
{
        protected IIocManager LocalIocManager;

        protected TestBaseWithLocalIocManager()
        {
            LocalIocManager = new IocManager();
        }

        public virtual void Dispose()
        {
            LocalIocManager.Dispose();
        }
}
```

Usage:

```
using (var myObject = LocalIocManager.ResolveAsDisposable<IMyObject>())
{
    //...
}
```

See sample https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/blob/dev/test/Abp.Tests/Authorization/AuthorizationInterceptor_Tests.cs#L47